# Translating Pseudocode steps into Python algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, input, pseudocode, area

I'm entirely new to programming and I'm supposed to turn pseudocode into a Python algorithm for a class assignment. I've tested mine algorithm (if you can even call it that) a few too many times and keep coming up with error messages. Any suggestions or resources that might be able to help would be greatly appreciated!

Pseudocode Order:

1. Declare Real radius
2. Declare Real area
3. Display “ Enter value for radius : “
4. Input radius
5. Set area = 3.14 * radius * radius
6. Display Area

Attempted Code:

```
radius = 1.0 
Area = 1.0 
print(" Enter value for radius : ") 
radius = input(" Enter value for radius : ") 
Area = 3.14 * radius * radius 
print(Area)
```

and the error:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Michelle, the Attempt look good, could you add also the real code and the error? It will help a lot

Comment: Sure. This is what I wrote in a Python Editor 5.2.0 IDE:                
 Radius = 1.0
Area = 1.0
print(“ Enter value for radius : “)
Radius = input(“ Enter value for radius : “)
Area = 3.14 * radius * radius
print(Area)                                                                                        
When I run it, this is the error message that appears:            
ParseError: bad token on line 3

Comment: Is there a way for me to show my actual code/format?

Comment: Is this what you got so far?

Comment: Input() will print the message given to it. No need to run a print again. You can learn from websites like https://medium.freecodecamp.com/tagged/python?gi=7717415099ad

Comment: `Radius` is different to `radius`

Comment: This problem is generated by a typographical error, and this is off-topic in SO

Comment: @eyllanesc I don't think so, it was a problem about programming, a type error not well handled

Comment: If you see the modifications that made the author you will realize that they are typographical errors.

Comment: So Michelle, welcome to stackoverflow! for future question, don't forget that there are a lot of good rules in this site, to make this place better and better, but don't worry, users will help you with comments and answers, but an advice I give you, next time you want to ask a question (or answer one! why not! is so good to help :)) I strongly recommend to read the how to ask page here! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it will help you and readers to understand your problem better, well, that's all, and very glad to help

Comment: The first error he had was: `NameError: name 'Radius' is not defined`

Comment: For me this kind of answers encourages the authors of the questions to continue asking questions of this type.

Comment: @eyllanesc no no, that was a misunderstanding, I take the time to make some questions to the OP, so I discovered she posted pseudo code, not actual code, and in a comment, she told that the problem was in the 3rd line, the part of the type error. At first I thought like you, but I was wrong also

Comment: That's even worse, because the author did not take the time to write his code correctly. And with these forms encourages them to continue doing the same and hoping that other responses are of that type.

Comment: @eyllanesc as a new user here, I'm here about 1 and 1/2 month active, for me, was better when other users explained to me what I was doing bad, in a question or an answer, and I only spend a little more time trying to understand what the OP was asking, considering it was the first question at all, and also I recommend to see the "how to ask", and edit the question, I think I prefer users than makes mistakes and then learns, than users getting ashamed because of a rude answer (with good intension).

Comment: My answer is not rude, I just claim that this question is off topic. You can do what seems good to you, but I prefer to be direct.

Comment: @eyllanesc "did not take the time to write *her* code correctly." Also, I'm sorry if this question was not in the proper area on this site. This is literally my third day of programming so I'm still getting used to a lot of the syntax rules; it's like learning an entirely new language! In the future, I'll be more contentious of that when I'm asking questions.

Comment: @eyllanesc I know the difference, and you are right, in all of it, I just put my self in the place of a new user at all, not used to short direct and correct answers. I wanted to save the question, by using the tools the system provides. There is a section available in some point to do just that :). I don't know. I hope you didn't take wrong my words, I just trying to make the world a bettter place :D

Comment: The problem is that these questions in SO questions generate a loss of quality, questions like for example: "aa" + 1 returns me error, problems of indentation, etc. And I think these should be eliminated from the start.

Comment: @eyllanesc nobody, thanks God, own the site to decide what question "generate a loss of quality" and "should be eliminated from the start", it is a total valid question, because from now, at least 13 people read this, and can vote to close the question, flag it, etc. You can't know how many hours a person can be stuck in a problem, maybe for you, is silly, easy, obvious, but not for everyone, and here is where it come sense that this can be a community... and this decision can be made by everybody... You really surprised me with your affirmation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I will add some explain to this:

```
radius = 1.0 #this is not mandatory, you can create the variable and assign the value in the same moment
area = 1.0 
radius = float(input(" Enter value for radius : ")) #here is so important to convert the input into a float, that's the other error you had
area = 3.14 * radius * radius t isn't working
print(area)
```

Comment: Yes. That's what I typed in and then it popped up with an error message on line 3.

Comment: Ahh, this makes total sense. So I just totally forgot the input. Thank you! :)

Comment: @MichelleMcGuire you are welcome! don't forget mak the answer as accepted if it was useful :)

Comment: @DamianLattenero Will do!

Answer (score 1):

`input()` returns a string, thus your TypeError.  You tried to multiply a string by a float.

Updated Code here:

```
radius = 1.0 
print("Enter value for radius : ") 
radius = input()
print(type(radius))
Area = 3.14 * (float(radius) * float(radius)) 
print(Area)
```

Output:

```
Enter value for radius : 
5
<class 'str'>
78.5
```

Comment: Yeeeees, very good explanation for someone who is starting, thats a plus one for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is:

```
import math
radius = input("Enter a radius: ")
area = math.pi * radius ** 2
print("The area is: " + str(area) + "cm squared.")
```

A few things happen here:

1. On the first line we import the math module, which contains a bunch of values (like π) and lots of methods (like tan). For more on modules, take  a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).
2. On the second line, we ask for the radius. Note that unlike lower level programming languages, we don't have to initialise it. Python figures out that it is an float (a decimal) by itself. EDIT: If you are using python 2, you **do** have to cast, just as Damien pointed out, by using `radius = float(input("Enter an area: ))`
3. On line three we set the area equal to πr^2. We call the math.pi value, which is very precise, then we multiply that by r ^ 2 (in python if we want to a to the power of b we write `a ** b`)
4. On line 4 we print the area as a String. Note that we have to cast the float area to be a string using the `str()` function. This is basically Java's easy way to print anything that isn't a string as a string (a collection of characters).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice one, with a lot of new info to take in, I really like it. Is a plus one baby!

Comment: Another comment, you forget to add the type, the code doesn't work if you don't tell after input make the input, take a look at my answer and you will see, or check your code here https://repl.it/languages/python3

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @DamianLattenero! I've adjusted the answer so that it is consistent with both Python 2 and 3. I'm coding in Python 3 so I didn't notice the error when running on my own machine :)